# Intent looping on rotation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I have a big activity with a lot of function (2 mediaplayer, 1 handler, 1 video record with surface)
I need to block the display orientation.
i write this on the "OnCreate()"

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

it's work fine on my test device (A tablet), but it doesn't work on phone (i've tested on a galaxy s4). The screen don't rotate, but i things, it call again the "Oncreate()" and i can't stop the mediaplayer.
some one have an idea?
thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Use this I will work 100%

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

add this line in onCreate()

Comment: I can't use this, because, if the user have a phone, it's layout orientation is portrait, so, the cam record on portrait, and the user can't use this function (or have a 90° rotate video)

Comment: You can check the screen resolution and make a simple if - smartphone orientation portratit else lanscape, I may have a example for this, 1 min to check